# application closing unexpectedly with very simple code

Tags: android, eclipse, audio, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I want to play a sound at the touch of a button,but application closing unexpectedly with very simple code.
**MainActivity.java:**

```
    package com.example.zvuki;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected Object MediaPlayer1 ;
public class TestSonido extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button br = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        br.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(TestSonido.this, R.raw.poeb);
            mp.start();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}

}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/texture_10_by_night_fate_stock"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="61dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="POEBEN" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The project does not give any error, in that I do not know what the problem is.

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat.  If you don't know how to, please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove android:onClick="onClick", what this will do is look for the method onClick in your activity to call when clicked, as you're setting the on click listener, it's redundant.

The alternative is to remove the setOnClickListener code and move your onClick(View view) code to the body of the class, for example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected Object MediaPlayer1 ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);           
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(TestSonido.this, R.raw.poeb);
        mp.start();   
    }

}
```

Comment: I did as you said. But I only have a white screen and do not have any buttons or background.

Comment: I'd remove the inner Activity, edited my code to reflect this.

Comment: I copied your code. White screen with bar. Ecslipse not give errors.

Comment: If I dont paste **public class TestSonido extends Activity{** then I have some trouble: **TestSonido cannot be resolved to a type**

Comment: I solved the problem: MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.poeb);